# PTR for Linux VM on Azure

Tags: linux, azure, ptr-record

I have a Linux (Ubuntu) virtual machine running on Azure and this machine runs a website that sends email to registered users. This emails are greylisted on some mailning services.

After some research, i realized that most probable cause is missing PTR record.

Next step - i start searching for means to create PTR record for my server.
I've found this article http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/07/21/announcing-reverse-dns-for-azure-cloud-services/ . It says, that it is possible to create PTR record by using azure PowerShell.

I`ve downloaded and installed azure-cli, that is a linux command line interface to manage azure services and resources. Unfortunately, in azure-cli there are no command to add PTR record for cloud service. Web-interface does not have such functionality either.

Is there any way to create PTR record for linux vm on azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to run the command from inside the Linux VM machine, you can run it virtually from anywhere that have PowerShell connected to your Azure subscription.

What you need to do is to install PowerShell on any Windows machine that is connected to the internet, and configure PowerShell to connect to your Azure Subscription remotely, there are two ways to do so:

1. Using the "**Add-AzureAccount**" PowerShell command.
2. Using the "**Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile**" and "**Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile**" PowerShell commands.

I won't go into details about which way is better, since they will end up serving your purpose of adding a PTR record for your cloud service. both methods are will documented in this link: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/install-configure-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the REST interface provided by Azure (aka Service Management API or SMAPI). Take a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cie/archive/2014/08/07/reverse-dns-for-azure-cloud-services-using-service-management-api.aspx for an example.